# How can I organize this mayavi code for speed up?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mayavi

I am writing a script for my physics project. My code ran 18hours and showed vector field.

`x`,`y`,`z` are coordinate matrices, and `c`, `e`, `f` are matrices that contain millions of vectors.

I have tried setting mask point but it didn't work.

```
vectors=mlab.pipeline.vector_field(x, y, z, c, e, f)

mlab.pipeline.vectors(vectors, mask_points = 100, scale_factor = 0.5, 
                          mode = "arrow", resolution = 8, line_width = 3)

mlab.show()
```

Does anyone know about a way of speeding up the execution please?

Comment: A clear formatting will be more confortable to read for other users, making them more likely to give an answer.

Comment: without a [running example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can only point you to [profiling your code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about starting with a small subset of all your fields to see how the execution time scales with the amount of data given? You would be looking at something like:

```
eachX = 100
eachY = 200
eachZ = 50
vectors = mlab.pipeline.vector_field(x[::eachX, ::eachY, ::eachZ],
                                     y[::eachX, ::eachY, ::eachZ],
                                     z[::eachX, ::eachY, ::eachZ],
                                     c[::eachX, ::eachY, ::eachZ],
                                     e[::eachX, ::eachY, ::eachZ],
                                     f[::eachX, ::eachY, ::eachZ])
```